# Swift Range on the fly 1...12.contains(1) Cannot invoke 'contains' with (Int)

Tags: swift, range

Is is not possible to create a range and call its contains method like this:

```
1...12.contains(1)
```

When I create a `var range = 1...12` and print its dynamicType I get a `Swift.Range<Swift.Int>`, so I'm guessing is not a type mismatch problem, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the problem was that of operator precedence:

```
(1...12).contains(1)   // -> true
```

(the code does look ambiguous otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

Another nice way to check this: (with the pattern match operator)

```
if 2...5 ~= 4 {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

place the range in parenthesis and it should work:

```
(1...12).contains(1)
```

Comment: Those are parenthesis, not brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. English is not my native language, so I thought that the term "brackets" (without any attributes such as square, curly, etc.) would mean "round" brackets. In the future I will use parenthesis instead.

Comment: In US English at least, the term brackets is used for "[ ]" and "{ }" (brackets and curly brackets/braces, respectively) and "( )" are known as parentheses.